# How to fix UnicodeEncodeError while using np.savetxt()?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, replace

I am trying to save an array as a text file using `np.savetxt()`. However I'm getting an error:
`UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u1ec7' in position 15: ordinal not in range(256)`

I checked what the character '\u1ec7' and its a LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH CIRCUMFLEX AND DOT BELOW.

I tried removing it from my text in the array using `x = x.replace("[^a-zA-Z#]", " ")` but it still gives an error.

What is this error exactly and what can be done to solve it?
Here's my code:

```
duplicate = X_train[y_train == 1]
not_duplicate = X_train[y_train == 0]

p = np.dstack([duplicate['question1'], duplicate['question2']]).flatten()
n = np.dstack([not_duplicate['question1'], not_duplicate['question2']]).flatten()

print ("Number of data points in class 1 (duplicate pairs) :",len(p))
print ("Number of data points in class 0 (non duplicate pairs) :",len(n))

#Saving the np array into a text file
np.savetxt('train_p.txt', p, delimiter=' ', fmt='%s', encoding = 'latin-1')
np.savetxt('train_n.txt', n, delimiter=' ', fmt='%s', encoding = 'latin-1')
```

var 'p' -

```
array(['how can i solve an encrypted  text  ',
       'where should i start to solve this encrypted  text  ',
       'how do i skip a class ', ..., 'how do know that you are in love ',
       'which is most beautiful place to visit  in kerala ',
       'which place in kerala is most beautiful '], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason that your text file needs to have Latin-1 encoding? Why not just use UTF-8?

Comment: `ệ` is not part of latin-1, so you need e.g. `encoding='utf-8'`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like simply omitting the `encoding` parameter works:

```
In [171]: '\u1ec7'                                                              
Out[171]: 'ệ'
In [172]: txt = ' '.join(['abc',_,_,'def',_])                                   
In [173]: txt                                                                   
Out[173]: 'abc ệ ệ def ệ'
```

works:

```
In [174]: np.savetxt('test.txt', [txt], fmt='%s')                               
In [175]: cat test.txt                                                          
abc ệ ệ def ệ
```

doesn't:

```
In [176]: np.savetxt('test.txt', [txt], fmt='%s', encoding='latin-1')           
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeEncodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-176-8ba623098d70> in <module>
----> 1 np.savetxt('test.txt', [txt], fmt='%s', encoding='latin-1')

<__array_function__ internals> in savetxt(*args, **kwargs)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py in savetxt(fname, X, fmt, delimiter, newline, header, footer, comments, encoding)
   1450     file : str or file
   1451         Filename or file object to read.
-> 1452     regexp : str or regexp
   1453         Regular expression used to parse the file.
   1454         Groups in the regular expression correspond to fields in the dtype.

UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u1ec7' in position 4: ordinal not in range(256)
```

The default for `encoding` is `None`, which get passed on to the `io.open` function:

```
In [185]: f = open('test','w', encoding=None)                                   
In [186]: f                                                                     
Out[186]: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='test' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>
```